# Implement the inherited abstract method?

Tags: java, syntax

I'm given error in my code but I'm not sure what the error means, I've tried researching the error but nothing seems to relate to my code, could anyone possibly help me out?

**My code;**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;


public class Assignment4Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("shop-account"));

    final int Username = 3387;
    final int Password = 5183;
    final int AccountNumber = 22334455;

    int EnteredUsername;
    int EnteredPassword;
    int EnteredAccountNumber;
    for (int s = 0; s <= 3; s++) {
        if (s < 3) {
            System.out.println("Enter Username");
            EnteredUsername = console.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Username Entered is " + EnteredUsername);
            System.out.println("Enter Password");
            EnteredPassword = console.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Password Entered is " + EnteredPassword);
            System.out.println("Enter Account Number");
            EnteredAccountNumber = console.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Account Number Entered is " + EnteredAccountNumber);
            if (Username == EnteredUsername && (Password == EnteredPassword)
                    && (AccountNumber == EnteredAccountNumber)) {
                System.out.println("Welcome");
                System.out.println("Account username, password, account number and current balance and shown below;");
                String line;
                while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
                new MyFrame().displayGui();
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong Username, Password or Account Number. Please try again.");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("3 incorrect enteries detected. Program is terminating, goodbye!");
        }
    }
}

static class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    JMenuBar menubar;

    JMenu TransferAnAmount;
    JMenuItem TransferAnAmountToAnotherAccount;

    JMenu ListRecentTransactions;
    JMenuItem ShowList;

    JMenu DisplayCurrentBalance;
    JMenuItem ShowBalance;

    JMenu ExitProgram;
    JMenuItem Exit;

    public MyFrame() {

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        menubar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menubar);

        TransferAnAmount = new JMenu("Transfer An Amount");
        menubar.add(TransferAnAmount);

        ListRecentTransactions = new JMenu("List Recent Transactions");
        menubar.add(ListRecentTransactions);

        DisplayCurrentBalance = new JMenu("Display Current Balance");
        menubar.add(DisplayCurrentBalance);

        ExitProgram = new JMenu("Exit Program");
        menubar.add(ExitProgram);

        TransferAnAmountToAnotherAccount = new JMenuItem("Transer an amount to another account");
        TransferAnAmount.add(TransferAnAmountToAnotherAccount);

        ShowList = new JMenuItem("Show List");
        ListRecentTransactions.add(ShowList);

        ShowBalance = new JMenuItem("Show Balance");
        DisplayCurrentBalance.add(ShowBalance);
        event s = new event();
        ShowBalance.addActionListener(s);

        Exit = new JMenuItem("Exit Program");
        ExitProgram.add(Exit);
        event e = new event();
        Exit.addActionListener(e);

    }

    class event implements ActionListener  {
        public void actionPerformed3(ActionEvent s) throws IOException {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("shop-account"));
            String line;
            while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
        public void actionPerformed4(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);

        }

    }

    public void displayGui() {
        MyFrame gui = new MyFrame();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setSize(600, 300);
        gui.setVisible(true);

    }

}
}
```

**I am given the error as this line in my code;**

```
    }

    class event implements ActionListener  { // <<< This line
        public void actionPerformed3(ActionEvent s) throws IOException {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("shop-account"));
            String line;
            while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
        public void actionPerformed4(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);

        }

    }
```

**Error given is;**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The type Assignment4Test.MyFrame.event must implement the inherited abstract method ActionListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent)
```

I'm not sure what the error is or how to fix it.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You need to implement the method `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent s)`. You may read about interfaces : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Comment: You're using Eclipse, right? So, go to the Window menu, and open the view named "Problems". This view should always be opened, and you shouldn't even try to launch your application while compilation errors are still listed in this view. Eclipse, BTW, probably warned you that you had non-compiling classes when you launched the program, but you probably chose to ignore the warning. Don't. And fix the compilation errors before starting the program.

Answer (score 1):

`ActionListener` interface contains the method `actionPerformed` so when you implement that interface it is mandatory to override the `actionPerformed` method. The correct definition of the method is :

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
```

Not sure whether it is just a typo but you have two methods `actionPerformed3` and `actionPerformed4` which are not actually overriding the `ActionListener` class `actionPerformed` method.

To avoid such problems it is always helpful to use the `@Override` annotation on top of the method you are trying to override. So this is better and safer:

```
@Override        
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {
           // method body
}
```

Comment: And you should use the @Override annotation, which helps detecting these kinds of errors early on.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I understand what you mean here but I am trying to create multiple functions for my menu but I have to change the name of either `actionPerformed3` or `actionPerformed4` to `actionPerformed` in order to `@Override`. But I can't have more than one `actionPerformed`. How would I create more than one `actionPerformed` and still be able to `@Override` all methods to ensure they all work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

[ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) is an interface.

Therefore, when implementing this interface, you are required to `override` the `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` method:

```
class MyListener implements ActionListener  { 
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // do something
        // maybe call actionPerformed3(e)?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement  `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`  inside your event class definition

```
class event implements ActionListener  {

    @Override   
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // you need to implement this
    }
            public void actionPerformed3(ActionEvent s) throws IOException {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("shop-account"));
                String line;
                while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            }
            public void actionPerformed4(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are Implementing an interface you need to override all the methods in it.

```
    @override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 

    {

    //some code.

    }
```

Add this code and try.

**Rule-: You have to override all the methods defined in an interface that you are implementing if your class is not abstract.**